# How can I encode multiple mediaStreamSource as one file in uwp?

Tags: uwp, screen-recording, wasapi, mediastreamsource, windows-graphics-capture

I want to record a section of my monitor and system audio. I will capture screen using wgc and audio using wasapi.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture-video

docs above says I can use mediaTranscoder to capture video. But it seems to accept only one mediaSourceStream. what can I do for adding Audio mediasourceStream captured by wasapi? I thought I can use mediaComposition to merge mutliple mediaStreamSource, but it doesn't support real-time capture stream.

If it were impossible in uwp, I will use windows media foundation. If you have an idea to record both system audio and screen ( and hopely mike input), please tell me.

Comment: Have you checked my reply about your question?

Comment: sorry I Just Checked your answer. Thank you for your advice. I will use MediaFoundation Sinkwriter because adding after record is not my option. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, UWP does not have related APIs that support simultaneous recording.  You need to capture separately and use [Windows.Media.Editing.MediaComposition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.editing.mediacomposition?view=winrt-22621) to add the audio to the video file.

[Capture audio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture#capture-audio)

[Screen capture to video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture-video)